# Embed quicktime movie. a "Play again" button at the end?

Tags: video, embed, media, quicktime

Forgive me if this was a silly question that I missed in the documentation, but I have no idea how this is done (having a "replay" button at the end of a video). I am guessing it's a callback to a javascript function when the movie ends? And load some new markup (with the replay button) in the function.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

That's usually something you see in Flash videos since the QuickTime transport controls are right there making such a feature somewhat redundant.

Comment: While that maybe true, but if you look at apple.com 's videos they all have a giant "watch again" button at the end. From a usability standpoint this is a great feature.